# Syntax error:missing ; before statement @(shell):1:15

Tags: mongodb, shell

I am trying to dump `.bson` files in mongo.But am getting this error continuously `Syntax error:missing ; before statement @(shell):1:15`
my query-to dump all files

```
mongorestore -d test d:\user\myProject\WebApp\Working_Site\db\
```

I tried this too..to dump single file

```
mongorestore-d test-c ci_sessions.bson d:\user\myProject\Working_Site\db\ci_sessions.bson
```

Comment: `mongorestore` to *dump*…?! You do realise that "dump" specifically means *from database into files*?

Comment: I dont know..I am new to this.Can you please suggest query to dump?

Comment: What exactly do *you* mean by "dump"? Database → file or file → database?

Comment: You are trying to run `mongorestore` from within the `mongo` shell. Exit the shell and run on the command line instead. And use `mongodump` to actually backup.

Comment: @Neil Lunn still  its showing same error

Comment: Exit the shell. Read what I said and what the linked answer says. You are in the mongo shell and you need to get out of it first.